# Activating an application as a child/popup of another application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Under Windows XP, is it possible to execute a 3rd party application, so its main window will be a child/popup window of my VC++ MFC application?

- I want to control it's Z-Order like any other window in my app
- I don't want it be be visible in the taskbar
- I want to catch its WM_CLOSE and handle it in my app

In general, I want my users to feel that this is just another dialog in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on hosting other applications in your application:
[Hosting .exe applications into a dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/exeHosting.aspx)

Also you may want to check out [hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx) and specifically the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` if you want to monitor all messages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about z-ordering and taskbar visibility, but you could go for [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).
I believe it would be prerfectly get the parent window's parameters and create a window as a child